# bing search api azure location based results

Tags: api, azure, search, bing

I am using the bing search api https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search to do searches and get the results back in json. This works however ....

When I do a search using the bing.com web page and search for say camping the results are biased towards my location (aberdeen)so I get campsites in aberdeen in the results. Is there any way I can add my location to the search query in the api to get the same location based results

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is not possible. According to their documentation you can pass in Lat / Long but it still does not bring back location based results.

I did some tests just to make sure by using their dataset explorer and it confirmed that location based results, even with a supplied lat/ long, does not work.

Example Query:
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27english%20pub%27&Latitude=26.3686&Longitude=80.1000